# Out of Office button

Tags: user, user-management, userrecordaccess

Scenario:
I'm the manager and I have an employee. My employee was on a sick leave so I want to put a message on his/her user profile that this employee is on a sick leave.

Problem:
The problem is when I open his profile I can't see the "Out of Office" button.

Question:
Can a user only see his own "Out of office" Button and not the "Out of office button" of other users? aside from admin which who can see everyone's "Out of office" button?

Thank you.

Comment: "Out of office" is a button or a checkbox ?

Comment: It is a standard button. I tried checking the page layout in the User Profile Page Layout and there is no Mobile & Lightning Actions. This is in the User Object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using UI but using APEX you can achieve this flow. We have `OutOfOffice` object available which you can use to create message for other users in your org using API/apex.

```
public static void set(Id userId, String message, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    // extract existing record
    Id outOfOfficeId;
    for(OutOfOffice o: [SELECT Id FROM OutOfOffice WHERE UserId = :userId]) {
        outOfOfficeId = o.Id;
    }
    upsert new OutOfOffice(
        Id = outOfOfficeId,
        UserId = userId,
        IsEnabled = true,
        StartDate=startDate,
        EndDate=endDate,
        message=message);
}
public static void reset(Id userId) {
    delete [SELECT Id FROM OutOfOffice WHERE UserId = :userId];
}
```

You can use this method to set/reset out of office.

Comment: Is this a Salesforce limitation?

Thank you buddy.

Comment: @Atoc I don't have any document to support my statement but I think yes. or may be missing permission.

Comment: There is a way for other users to see the Out Of Office button and this is by giving them an Administrative Permission Manage user which is not advisable. :) thank you for the answer.